# Window appearance without style in C++ Qt application scheduled in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, cron

When I normally run my application from the command line it looks like this:

[image]

However, when I schedule the command using the crontab (or the "at" command), the window looks like this:

[image]

The command that I schedule is as follows: "export DISPLAY=:0.0 && myprogram". I use Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit.

Any idea how to get the nice appearance for the scheduled window? Thank you.

Comment: Answer updated, check it out I have added another possible approach to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Program started from crontab has different environment. So you can create a shell script that sources your profile, for example using bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.profile
export DISPLAY=:0.0
exec myprogram
```

And run that from crontab. If you do not normally use bash, you may need to use script with shell that you use.

Alternative would be to investigate your profile and find out, what difference in environment changes window appearance. Then export that variable in such script, or put it directly into crontab job, like you do for variable `DISPLAY`.

Comment: I would prefer to avoid replicating the whole profile if possible.
Still, I tried putting some individual variables like DISPLAY (I omitted copying stuff like session IDs), but unfortunately I couldn't locate the one which is responsible for the problem.

Comment: @AlexSee first make sure that `.profile` does change window appearance. Then you can look into there and find which particular variable changes it. Otherwise dump your current env: `set > env.sh` and check that it works. Then you can remove variables from there and find the culprit.

Comment: This solution works. Alternatively, would it be possible to somehow source the profile from crontab (something like scheduling "source ~/.profile; exec myprogram", which doesn't work)?

Comment: source ~/.profile did not chance the GUI style for me. Anyone found the environment variable that changes the windows display style?

Answer (score 3):

I think that when you run the program using the crontab the program is running with other environmet. Environment that don't have the configurations you already do.

For instance, in your user space you said `QT` theme that you want it looks like `GNOME`.

This can happend if the user root runs the app since root has a different environment, hence different setting for `QT` gui themes/appareance.

Possible solution, try to specify the environment which will run the app.

Another solution could be select the theme programatically, [here](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/7632) you have a discussion about the subject.

**Test:** Try running the app yourself as root, and compare result. Don't use `sudo`. Try with `su -c`.

Comment: No when you run program through crontab it runs it as user, unless you use sudo when updating/creating crontab record

Comment: The command is indeed in my crontab (not root's), however, when I run the command as the root, the problem is replicated.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda because environment is different

Comment: So, crontab runs the scritps in a different environment right?

Comment: @RaydelMiranda right, but not for root, unless you use crontab as root

Comment: @Slava and in what environment it runs by default? What is the real problem of the question OP then?

Comment: @RaydelMiranda what environment crond has by default. Problem that environment is different, not that program runs as root

Comment: @Slava I update my answer according to your critic, can you give me my upvote back?

Comment: EDIT: I wanted to use the programmatic solution, but it turned out that it worked only for one style, namely QWindowStyle (no idea why).
So I used the solution posted by @Slava.